# What is the clearest way to name resources in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

What naming conventions do you use for resource files and IDs and what benefits do they bring?

It's very easy for example to end up with a view ID like "activity_settings_location_text_label" but quickly becomes unmanageable and messy. I've not seen any guidance from Google on this, did I miss it?

Resources can be "grouped" using hierarchical naming, but what structure works best for each resource type? String, color, dimens, layouts, includes, etc

My naming is currently fairly ad-hoc, and it's clear I need better structure (particularly so I can find IDs more easily using the IDE's code-completion).

Comment: I don't even use the `_`, lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most important thing to remember, I think, is that it's perfectly fine to use the same ID across multiple layouts. For example, `@id/title_bar` is clean and generic and works, and so much simpler than `@id/settings_title_bar`, `@id/home_screen_title_bar`, `@id/search_title_bar` and so on.

I also like to name layouts destinated for activities as `@layout/activity_home` and `@layout/activity_search` etc. Drawables and icons should adopt the same standards as Android uses, i.e. `@drawable/ic_btn_explode` and `@drawable/ic_dialog_exploded`.

Includes can be tricky, but simpler ones which consist of only a few elements and serve a single, precise purpose tend to end up as `@layout/loading` or `@layout/error_message`.

I'm still working on naming strings sensibly, but again short, concise names make the whole process a lot easier.

Comment: For icon prefixes see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#design-tips

Comment: "it's perfectly fine to use the same ID across multiple layouts". This everything I needed to hear today.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no official guidelines about this, I'd recommend.

- Be consistent.
- Be practical.
- Whenever possible, try to follow the style of the Android source code and [android.R](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html).

Answer (score 3):

So 4 years later... Here is a list of ['best-practices'](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices) I adhere to when developing for android.

[Here is the section regarding resources](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices#resources)

---

For example when naming **`string`** resources, these are the goods and bads

> #strings.xml
>
> Name your strings with keys that resemble namespaces, and don't be
> afraid of repeating a value for two or more keys. Languages are
> complex, so namespaces are necessary to bring context and break
> ambiguity.
>
> ##Bad
>
> ```
> <string name="network_error">Network error</string>
> <string name="call_failed">Call failed</string>
> <string name="map_failed">Map loading failed</string>
> ```
>
> ##Good
>
> ```
> <string name="error_message_network">Network error</string>
> <string name="error_message_call">Call failed</string>
> <string name="error_message_map">Map loading failed</string>
> ```

---

**P.S** If you are using Android Studio, refactoring is a total breaze. It works for almost everything. Not just java code.

Just place your cursor's caret on an ID and hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to rename and automatically refactor. Useful for changing IDs on the fly

Comment: Just a quick note on the "Good" approach here. Using "." to as a namespace separator will be an issue when you do databinding, as say when you write `R.string.error.message.network` it will try to parse `R.string.error` and fail at it.

Comment: "Shift+F6 on the id to do refactor". Saved three hours of my life <3

Comment: You can't follow the "good" approach. A full stop is not allowed in a resource name.

Comment: Updated to reflect the linked updated guidance (use `_` to namespace instead of `.`)

Answer (score 2):

I do it like: `home_search_btn` that means its a a button, meant for searching something, and will be used in the activity named `Home`

Answer (score 2):

My approach, which has been working quite well is where a resource should be put in a particular XML file, for example you would typically put a Color definition in colors.xml or a string of text in strings.xml the resource file is part of the path, so instead of:

```
R.string.home_button_text
```

I would have:

```
R.string.home_button
```

I know it's a literal string because of the R.string part. To me this is more readable than putting "text" on the end of the id.

On occasion however it might not be obvious what resource type something is, in which case I make the id a bit more descriptive.